# AWS Redshift failed to inflateinvalid or incomplete deflate data while inserting a zipped csv file

Tags: amazon-web-services, gzip, redshift

I have a zipped csv file which is a part of a huge file, and extracted from the original huge file using the following command:

```
gunzip -c myFile.csv.gz | head -n 500000 > myFile.csv.gz_p1
```

after making the smaller file, I need to insert it into a table in Redshift, but I get the following error:

```
Cause: Failed to inflateinvalid or incomplete deflate data. zlib error code: -3
```

Comment: myFile.csv`.gz`_p1 <- highlighted portion causing trouble somewhere? or doubly gzippped data?

Comment: I don't know, and would you please clarify what do you mean by  doubly gzippped data? is there any data zipped twice?

Comment: There apparently is some kind of trouble with how your data is stored. `echo TEST | gzip -c | gzip -c | od -t x1z` displays the result of compressing "TEST" 'doubly' (twice).